# Will upgrading my Unlocked, Rooted (fastboot + superboot method) Galaxy Nexus from 4.0.1 to 4.0.2 brick the phone?

Tags: rooting, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I can re-root if necessary, but we just paid $700 for the phone, and I don't want to brick it.

From what I can tell, upgrading will cause me to have to re-root and unlock the boot loader, which I can do again using the instructions I orignally used to root 4.0.1 (These Instructions)

Will this upgrade brick my phone?

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe it might?  Is there a reason you don't just flash the original firmware and re-lock the bootloader?

Comment: Well, I know people that upgraded iOS and it broke their jailbreaks, and many reports online of bricked phones when trying to upgrade the OS on a jailbroken/rooted phone...nothing Android specific that I've seen really, especially for 4.0.2 since it's so new, but boss would not be happy if I bricked our brand-new phone.

Comment: Well I want the bootloader unlocked, but I just did the upgrade. Lost root, but don't see why I can't just re-root it. I don't know how to re-flash the original firmware, I'm new to Android (we got the phone for the NFC capability, as we are developing an NFC application for use with Android and in the future, the iPhone.).    Thanks for the replies! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, doing the OTA update to 4.0.2 from 4.0.1 did not brick anything. Superuser is still installed and apps that require root supposedly have root permissions, but they claim they do not.

I will attempt to re-root it, as I don't see why that will be an issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can unlock the bootloader before re-rooting your phone, but the phone will wipe (this is unavoidable!), so back up first...and **COPY YOUR BACKUPS OFF THE PHONE**